# setfacl rwx permission does not override the default permissions

Tags: linux, unix, redhat

```
[user4@localhost /]$ getfacl /accounting
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: accounting
# owner: root
# group: accounting
# flags: -st
user::rwx
user:user4:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::---
default:user::rwx
default:user:user4:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::---
```

User 4 should be able to modify any file created by any users inside the /accounting directory. But whe he tries to do so, it says permission denied.

```
[user4@localhost /]$ cd /accounting/
[user4@localhost accounting]$ ll
total 8
-rw-r-----+ 1 user1 accounting 0 May 19 18:28 1
[user4@localhost accounting]$ echo hello >> 1
bash: 1: Permission denied
[user4@localhost accounting]$
```

I am new to this and I am not sure what i am doing wrong. please help out! thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> User 4 should be able to modify any file created by any users inside the /accounting directory.

Incorrect. Directory permissions only apply to directory operations, not any files contained within it. So while user4 can *delete* files within the directory (since this is a directory operation), they cannot modify files they do not have explicit permissions for.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio. Doesn't using setfacl d:u:user4 /accounting instead of setfacl u:user4 /accounting enable inheritance to its files and subdirectories? If not, Could you please tell me how to enable this using setfacl. thanks again!

Comment: There is no such thing as "inheritance" for existing files.